# What packages are needed on Ubuntu 10.04 to run programs compiled with gcc/g++ 4.7?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, shared-libraries

What do I need to do on a fresh, updated ubuntu 10.04 machine to run programs written in c++11, compiled with gcc 4.7? Is an stdlibc++ update enough? glibc? Anything else? Rephrased: which packages do I need to deploy on a ubuntu 10.04 machine so that my gcc 4.7 c++11 programs will run, without installing the complete gcc suite?

I would like to develop applications for a ubuntu 10.04 based system and be able to use the c++11 language and library features available in gcc 4.7. (Note that a special ppa is needed on ubuntu 10.04 to install gcc 4.7, otherwise it will currently stick to gcc 4.4). I do NOT want to deploy a compiler on the machine that will run the applications I create. I don't plan on using "fancy" libraries like GOMP or anything.

Comment: You'll get a definitive answer from the loader if you just try it.  You can get virtualbox and a 10.04 .iso installed in about ten minutes.

Comment: If it's feasible in terms of size restrictions and similar things: Link your app statically?

Comment: Thanks to you all. Size does matter in this case, so that was not an option. And sure, I can make a test program and see what it requires, but I wanted to know what future version may need and install it all from the get-go. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `libgcc_s.so.1`, `libstdc++.so.6.0.17` and `libsupc++.so.6.0.17` libraries from GCC 4.7, but I doubt that Ubuntu 10.04 has packages containing those libraries.  The PPA you used to get GCC 4.7 should also provide those libs, either in the `gcc` package or some other ones, such as `libgcc1` and `libstdc++6`

If you can't find `.deb` packages for them then the only reliable way to get those libraries on an older system is to build GCC, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC for pointers. You can use `--enable-languages=c,c++` to avoid building the compiler front-ends and runtime libs you don't need.

Comment: After installing gcc-4.7 using the package from this [ppa](http://ppa.lauanchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu), I don't have libsupc++. "locate libsup" doesn't reveal anything after doing updatedb. That also means it wasn't installed with gcc-4.4.
[http://wiki.osdev.org/Libsupcxx](http://wiki.osdev.org/Libsupcxx) seems to suggest it is only required when doing cross compilation. This is not the case for me. Is this what you expect?

Comment: Also, I notice that libgcc_s.so.1 is not present after installing gcc-4.7. libgccpp.so.1 is present (from package libgc1c2).

Comment: No, libsupc++.so has nothing to do with cross-compilation. libgccpp.so is a completely different library, from the Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage collector